# Stream#reduce results unexpected type, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: java, java-stream, java-11

I have a simple Gradle project:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'application'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

sourceCompatibility = '11'
targetCompatibility = '11'

mainClassName = 'demo.Main'

dependencies {
    compile 'net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy:1.9.13'
}
```

There's only one Java file in the project:

```
package demo;

import java.awt.*;
import java.util.stream.*;
import net.bytebuddy.agent.builder.*;
import net.bytebuddy.matcher.*;

import static net.bytebuddy.matcher.ElementMatchers.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // This compiles
        new AgentBuilder.Default().
            type(nameStartsWith("com.demo").or(is(Point.class))
        );


        var typeSpec = Stream.of(nameStartsWith("com.demo"), is(Point.class)).reduce(ElementMatcher.Junction::or).orElseThrow();

        // This does not compile
        new AgentBuilder.Default().type(typeSpec);
    }   
}
```

I was expecting `Stream.of(nameStartsWith("com.demo"), is(Point.class)).reduce(ElementMatcher.Junction::or).orElseThrow()` to yield the same type as `type(nameStartsWith("com.demo").or(is(Point.class))`, however it does not and causes compilation to fail:

```
/code/compile-error/src/main/java/demo/Main.java:18: error: incompatible types: invalid method reference
                var typeSpec = Stream.of(nameStartsWith("com.demo"), is(Point.class)).reduce(ElementMatcher.Junction::or).orElseThrow();
                                                                                             ^
    method or in interface Junction<S> cannot be applied to given types
      required: ElementMatcher
      found: Junction<? extends NamedElement>,Junction<? extends NamedElement>
      reason: inference variable U has incompatible upper bounds CAP#2,CAP#1
  where S,U are type-variables:
    S extends Object declared in interface Junction
    U extends CAP#1 declared in method <U>or(ElementMatcher<? super U>)
  where CAP#1,CAP#2 are fresh type-variables:
    CAP#1 extends NamedElement from capture of ? extends NamedElement
    CAP#2 extends NamedElement from capture of ? extends NamedElement
Note: Some messages have been simplified; recompile with -Xdiags:verbose to get full output
1 error
```

Any ideas why the result of `Stream/reduce` is failing to compile?

Comment: What is the compile error?

Comment: Please read "How to create a [mcve]". Then use the [edit] link to improve your question (do not add more information via comments). Otherwise we are not able to answer your question and help you.

Comment: I have rewrote the question with full details. can you please unclose?

Answer (score 1):

When you write `type(nameStartsWith("com.demo").or(is(Point.class)))`, the method invocation `type` provides the context for the method `or`, which provides a context for the method `is`.

There is a lot of flexibility in the ByteBuddy API taking advantage of the fact that these are matchers, so a matcher being able to check instances of type X can also check instances of subtypes of X.

E.g. the method signature of

```
<T extends TypeDefinition> ElementMatcher.Junction<T> is(Type type)
```

allows to infer `TypeDescription` for `T` which is a subtype of of `TypeDefinition`.

But also the signature

```
<U extends S> ElementMatcher.Junction<U> or(ElementMatcher<? super U> other);
```

allows to infer a more specific type `U` extending both matcher’s types, so if you used

```
ElementMatcher.Junction<NamedElement> a = nameStartsWith("com.demo");
ElementMatcher.Junction<TypeDefinition> b = is(Point.class);
var combined = a.or(b);
new AgentBuilder.Default().type(combined);
```

The compiler could infer the type `ElementMatcher.Junction<TypeDefinition>` as type for `combined`, whereas the signature of

```
void type(ElementMatcher<? super TypeDescription> typeMatcher)
```

will accept a matcher of that type, as `TypeDefinition` is a supertype of `TypeDescription`.

---

In contrast, when you create a `Stream` via

```
Stream.of(nameStartsWith("com.demo"), is(Point.class))
```

there is no possibility to exploit the special nature of matchers; the compiler has to find a common basetype for `ElementMatcher.Junction<NamedElement>` and `ElementMatcher.Junction<TypeDefinition>`, which will end up at `ElementMatcher.Junction<? extends NamedElement>`, as `NamedElement` is a supertype of `TypeDefinition`.

Then, the subsequent `reduce` tries to apply `or` with a wildcard type and even worse, the signature, `reduce(BinaryOperator<T>)` requires a function accepting two inputs of the same type, returning that type, as it might be fed as input to the reduction function again. So it is not capable of exploiting the relaxed type signature of the `or` method.

If you enforce a more specific type for the `nameStartsWith` method invocation like

```
var typeSpec = Stream.of(
        ElementMatchers.<TypeDefinition>nameStartsWith("com.demo"),
        is(Point.class))
    .reduce(ElementMatcher.Junction::or).orElseThrow();
new AgentBuilder.Default().type(typeSpec);
```

it will work. It will also work when enforcing the type at the stream, e.g.

```
var typeSpec = Stream.<ElementMatcher.Junction<TypeDefinition>>of(
        nameStartsWith("com.demo"),
        is(Point.class))
    .reduce(ElementMatcher.Junction::or).orElseThrow();
```

as the type of the `Stream.of` method invocation can be used for inferring the types for the `nameStartsWith` invocation.

Generally, types can propagate through nested method invocations, but not through chained invocations, so with the chain `Stream.of(…).reduce()`, the function used in `reduce` can not help inferring the types for the `of` invocation.